# bool property without Required attribute is required

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

have a simple ViewModel with three properties like so:

```
public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
```

In my view I have a simple `@Html.CheckBoxFor(p => p.RememberMe)`
I am using Client Side validation enabled using `Html.EnableClientValidation();`

Why is this being set as a required field?

Comment: It's not related to this bug in some older browsers is it? https://github.com/jzaefferer/jquery-validation/issues/598

Comment: You can use either `bool?` for property or use a hidden input (<input type="hidden" name="RememberMe"/>)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try a nullable bool.

```
public bool? RememberMe { get; set; }
```

With reference types there are a number of default validation rules applied. If a reference type is not nullable, it becomes required by default. The best illustration of this is if you use a textbox to display some properties (not something you would do in your site, but good for testing purposes):

Model:

```
public bool? MyBool { get; set; }
public int MyInt { get; set; }
```

View:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.MyBool)
 @Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.MyInt)
```

You can see from a view source what happens on the page:

```
<input id="MyNullBool" name="MyNullBool" type="text" value="">
<input data-val="true" data-val-required="The MyBool field is required." id="MyBool" name="MyBool" type="text" value="False">
<input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MyInt must be a number." data-val-required="The MyInt field is required." id="MyInt" name="MyInt" type="text" value="0">
```

The nullable bool has no validation attributes, whereas the bool has a `data-val-required` tag. The int has a `data-val-required` tag and a `data-val-number` attribute

Of course, on a checkbox this is all pretty redundant as it can only be checked (true) or not checked (false) so a required tag isn't much use.

Comment: Also note that mvc will validate the model when it's posted back so if you put something that it can't bind to a bool in the textbox, ModelState.IsValid will be false and have a ModelState error.

Comment: Interesting but I suppose it makes sense now.  I noticed in your example you're using a input type text instead of the Html.CheckBoxFor; does this mean that the checkbox helper is useless?

Comment: With `CheckBoxFor` it says "Cannont implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'"

Answer (score -2):

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(c => c.TermsAndConditions, new { required = "required" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(c => c.TermsAndConditions, "you must agree to terms and conditions of Service.)"
```